# What is the difference between DefaultHandler(Message) and "inherited" in message handlers?

Tags: delphi

What exactly is the difference between calling `DefaultHandler(Message)` and `inherited` in a message handlers. e.g:

```
TScrollBox = class(TScrollingWinControl)
private
  ...
  procedure WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage); message WM_NCHITTEST;
  ...
end;

procedure TScrollBox.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  DefaultHandler(Message);
end;
```

Why not call `inherited` here? when should I use either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let us consider the example that you provide. Suppose that instead of calling `DefaultHandler`, inherited was called (or equivalently no `WM_NCHITTEST` message handler was implemented by TScrollBox). In that scenario the message would be processed by `TWinControl` in this method:

```
procedure TWinControl.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TWMNCHitTest);
begin
  with Message do
    if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and (FParent <> nil) then
      Result := HTCLIENT
    else
      inherited;
end;
```

This performs special treatment when designing, otherwise it calls inherited which ultimately leads to a call to `DefaultHandler` which forwards the message to the default window procedure.

Now, `TScrollBox` replaces that message handler with this one:

```
procedure TScrollBox.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  DefaultHandler(Message);
end;
```

That calls `DefaultHandler` directly, and so unconditionally forwards the message to the default window procedure.

So, what we conclude from this is that `TScrollBox.WMNCHitTest` simply changes behaviour at designtime by suppressing the code in `TWinControl.WMNCHitTest` which returns `HTCLIENT`.

I presume therefore that this was the motivation of the author of this VCL code. By using `DefaultHandler` the behaviour of the underlying window (as determined by the default window procedure) is restored, removing any behaviour modifications implemented by the intervening VCL code.

Comment: If you are writing message handler, decide what to do with the message (e.g. this message is a nice example where you should clearly define message result, not rely on what `DefaultHandler` provides).

Comment: I am not attempting to cast judgement, I'm just explaining what the code in the question does. Petty revenge voting isn't pretty.

Comment: @Victoria, `this message is a nice example where you should clearly define message result, not rely on what DefaultHandler provides` So how do you suggest this message should have been handled otherwise?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, What would have happen happen if that message handler was empty? shouldn't there be a default handler in that case?

Comment: @zig In my opinion the message result is clearly defined. It is simply whatever the default window procedure provides. That's how you should interpret calls `DefaultHandler` in subclasses of `TWinControl`.

Comment: @zig What do you mean "if that message handler was empty"? Can you be precise?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, `procedure TScrollBox.WMNCHitTest(var Message: TMessage);
begin end;` or returning `Message.Result := 1`.

Comment: The former is a mistake because the window procedure is contracted to return a value. The latter is a misleading way to return `HTCLIENT` since it so happens that `HTCLIENT` has value `1`.

Answer (score 2):

It is very hard to be sure in specific cases. DefaultHandler handles (in theory) *all messages* where a message handler handles only one. Default Handler is a public virtual method and so can be overridden explicitly. Message handlers are not declared virtual, and are usually private anyway, so for example in your code if you replace

```
inherited;
```

by

```
inherited WMNCHitTest( message );
```

the compile will fail.

The other issue is which ancestor overrides what. So one ancestor may override the Message Handler, and another may override Default Handler, which makes it very confusing without a lot of digging.

So I guess for me I have to fall back on what seems best for documentation. Which means, in general, I would use inherited, because I am falling back on the ancestors implementation of this particular message, not the ancestors implementation for messages in general.

Which I guess is another way of saying - I would go with Victoria's approach.

Comment: There is a clear difference in behaviour. If in `TScrollBox.WMNCHitTest` the call to `DefaultHandler` is replaced with `inherited`, then designtime behaviour will be changed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Which really only reinforces what I am saying. You either need to dig or go with the flow. Personally I am not prepared to dig in every case. But I will modify the first line, since as you point out it is not accurate in this case.

Comment: This misses the point in my view. The code in the question calls `DefaultHandler` for a very specific reason.

Comment: Yes, for a sort of _runtime override_ which can be rarely used. If I'll be handling certain message, I know how. If my control will have scroll bars that need to respond at designtime, I say it so in that message.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I understand what you are saying, but the question was more general, and so I was trying to answer in a more general way.

Comment: I'm not sure I see your point about `Message handlers are not declared virtual, and are usually private anyway`. calling `inherited` will inherit the ancestor message handler.

Comment: @zig yes, it will call the ancestors message handler. But this is not the normal form of inheritance, that is all I am saying. Normally you cannot inherit from a private method.

Comment: Message methods are overriden if they match the message (no matter what method name you use). And calling `inherited` starts calling all the implementations in the class hierarchy (that call `inherited`) until it reaches `TObject.DefaultHandler`. If you call `DefaultHandler`, all `DefaultHandler` overrides are called (so long `inherited` methods are called) until `TObject.DefaultHandler`. In any case, you must know what they implement.

Comment: @Victoria good point. So in effect 'inherited' in this case does not mean what inherited would normally mean at all. It means 'pass the message to my ancestor'. A way of saying 'I am adding to functionality' as opposed to 'I am replacing functionality'

Comment: @dsm, yep, that's it. And `DefaultHandler` you can treat as some sort of _runtime override_ of message handler. Still, you must know what ancestors implement, no matter if you call `inherited` in a message handler, or `override` the `DefaultHandler`. If I decide to handle message I need to know what happens when I call `inherited` so as if I call `DefaultHandler` inside it (inheritance still works, and it's not an *accident* to handle a message).